# Ruby programmatically installing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I install a gem programmatically using Backticks in script with `gem install gem_name` as:

```
if not_gem_installed
  `gem install my_gem`
end

require 'my_gem'
```

and then require the gem, a `LoadError` comes up. Any way to fix this?

Comment: try update ruby version

Comment: did you add  **require 'rubygems'**  to your gemfile?

Comment: @YunusHatipoglu I am installing gem programatically using Backticks.

Comment: Please add ruby code where you are "requiring" the gem and raising the `LoadError`.

Comment: @Uzbekjon I have updated my question to include code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried installation of gems with backticks and found that I have the same issues as mentioned in question. I see that it's not the optimal choice for this job.
I would suggest to use Gem for search of gems and installation.

```
require 'rubygems/commands/install_command'

def find_or_install(gem_name)
  Gem::Specification::find_by_name(gem_name)
rescue Gem::LoadError
  install_gem(gem_name)
end

def install_gem(gem_name)
  cmd = Gem::Commands::InstallCommand.new
  cmd.handle_options [gem_name]     

  cmd.execute
rescue Gem::SystemExitException => e
  puts "FAILURE: #{e.exit_code}"
end
```

https://gist.github.com/adamjmurray/3154437 - Gist with good examples

Comment: I think the reason maybe because with backticks the command is executed in subshell current shell running script env isn't updated.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are not using RubyGems, you need to require specific file from your gem's path. RubyGems overrides the `require` method so that it looks for paths file to include from gem paths in your `Gemfile`. So, make sure you specify correct path to your gem's main .rb file.

```
if not_gem_installed
  `gem install my_gem`
end

require 'path/to/my_gem'
```

You can check the paths ruby will look into by printing the value of `$:` in your file/irb or by running `gem environment` command in your command line.

```
uzbekjon@mini:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/uzbekjon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/uzbekjon/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/etc
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
     - /Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     ...

=== OR with $: ===

uzbekjon@mini:~$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > $:
 => ["/Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib", "/Users/uzbekjon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0", "..."]
```

### Alternatively

You can require simply use bundler in your script.

```
if not_gem_installed
  `gem install my_gem`
end

require 'rubygems'         # <= This line here
require 'path/to/my_gem'
```